# How to fix number of API requests per second (delaying request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, delay

I'm using an open API which has quota for the max number of requests per second (1 / sec).

So, I want to have a floating delay before making the next request. I could do the fixed one, but then that would take more time to process (cause after request it saves the data to the db, which takes x amount of time).

I've tried writing something like this:

```js
'use strict'

const request = require('request-promise')

var last_request_time = 0

const makeRequest = (param1, param2, callback) => {
  let current_request_time = Date.now()

  setTimeout(() => {
    last_request_time = current_request_time // doesn't change "last_request_time"
    
    request({
      uri: encodeURI(`/url/${param1}/${param2}`),
      json: true
    }).then(data => {
      return callback('ok', data)
    }).catch(error => {
      return callback('error', error)
    })
  }, 1000 - (current_request_time - last_request_time))
}

module.exports = makeRequest
```

But it doesn't work without changing `last_request_time` just before the API request. How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var last_request_time = 0;
const makeRequest = (param1, param2, callback) => {
 let current_request_time = Date.now();

 setTimeout(() => {
  // doesn't change "last_request_time"

   request({
   uri: encodeURI(`/url/${param1}/${param2}`),
   json: true
  }).then(data => {
    return callback('ok', data);
  }).catch(error => {
    return callback('error', error);
   });
 }, 1000 - (current_request_time - last_request_time));
 last_request_time = current_request_time;
};
```

If you have it inside the timeout function it wont change the out side value